# Luabind: How can I use a table's stored values when calling a function inside of it?

Tags: c++, luabind

I am creating tables in Lua and storing them as Luabind objects. Then, I wish to call a function stored in one of these tables, so I would do something like this

```
data["onPrimaryFire"](player, x, y, a);
```

This `data` has a field named `ammo` inside of it. However, I am unable to reference this field inside the `onPrimaryFire` function. It is returned as `nil`. I know I can fix this by passing `data` as a parameter to the function, however that feels weird and unnecessary. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes- Lua contains syntactic sugar to make calling member functions simple.

First, consider this alternate way of writing and calling your function:

```
function data.onPrimaryFire( aPlayer, aX, aY, aA )
    -- do stuff, but cannot access data
end

data.onPrimaryFire( player, x, y, a )
```

You define the function, then call it. In order to do what you want, you need to pass data in as a parameter:

```
function data.onPrimaryFire( aMyData, aPlayer, aX, aY, aA )
    -- do stuff, aMyData.ammo is accessible
end

data.onPrimaryFire( data, player, x, y, a )
```

As you say, this is cumbersome, but Lua has a shortcut which reproduces this model- using ':' instead of '.'

```
function data:onPrimaryFire( aPlayer, aX, aY, aA )
    -- do stuff, self.ammo is accessible
end

data:onPrimaryFire( player, x, y, a )
```

So, what happens here is that, when you call data:onPrimaryFire(), the data table is automatically passed in as the first (invisible) parameter to the function. Inside the called function it is referred to as "self".

When using this form, be careful to be consistent! If you use ":" to define the function, but "." when calling it, you will pass "player" in as "self" and all your parameters will be wrong. You can however mix and match the forms if you understand how it all works. For instance:

```
function data.onPrimaryFire( aSelf, aPlayer, aX, aY, aA )
    -- do stuff, aSelf.ammo is accessible
end

data:onPrimaryFire( player, x, y, a )
```